# can we make relationship between to two unique constraints in different tables?

Tags: oracle, relationships

I have two tables, table A ,table B 
Both tables having primary , unique constraints

I want make relationship with table A unique constraints, to table B unique constraints,

Comment: what kind of relationship?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

This would work:

```
create table s(id int primary key, n int unique);
create table t(id int primary key, n int unique references s(n));
```

Comment: Thanks for valuable answer .  Can this is possible for composite unique constraints ?